# Adding checkbox ID to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having some difficulties when trying to iterate thru all checkbox to see if they are checked and add them into an array and perform some filter after that using JavaScript. Here is my code for checkbox:

```
 var content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
content += "<tr><td><input class=\"pss\"  type=\"checkbox\" checked='checked' onclick=\"toggleOverlayer('pss')\">Show Label</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td><div id=\"pss\"></div></td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td>Development Type</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select1' value='Commercial and Residential' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)' >Commercial and Residential</td><td><input id='type_select2' value='Commercial' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)' >Commercial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select3' value='Heavy Vehicle Park' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Heavy Vehicle Park</td><td><input id='type_select4' value='Hospital' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Hospital</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select5' value='Hotel' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Hotel</td><td><input id='type_select6' value='Industrial' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Industrial</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select7' value='Industrial-White' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Industrial-White</td><td><input id='type_select8' value='Office' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Office</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='type_select9' value='Recreation' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Recreation</td><td><input id='type_select10' value='Residential (Landed)' class=\"pssCheckBox\"  type=\"checkbox\" onclick='queryPSS(this)'>Residential (Landed)</td></tr>";
content += "</table>"
```

And the jQuery to iterate thru checkbox:

```
function queryPSS(idValue) {
var type_filter = new Array();
$(":checkbox").each(function(index, element) {
if(idValue.checked == true)
{
   type_filter.push(idValue.value);
       }
});

filterString = "";

for(var i =0; i < type_filter.length; i++)
{
    filterString += "devt_type_code in ('" + type_filter[i] + "' +)";
}
}
```

However, when I execute the code, the array contains nothing. I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It push the checked one into the array but with repetitive elements. Let's say I checked Industrial, it will add 10 Industrial into the array

Comment: What is idValue here? I would replace it with `this` instead.

Comment: oh sorry, idValue is the checkbox value which pass along when onclick

Comment: ...and you are pushing this exact same value multiple times in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this is what you want to achieve,

```
var type_filter = new Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        type_filter.push(id);
    });
});

function queryPSS(idValue) {
    var id = $(idValue).attr('id');

    if( $( idValue ).is(":checked") ){
        // Add Checked ID            
        type_filter.push(id);
    }
    else {
        // Remove Unchecked id
        type_filter.remove(id);
    }

    console.log(type_filter);
}

// Helps to remove element from array
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/WkNH3/

Comment: It does not work. The first item always 'on' no matter what I selected

Comment: Nope, it does not work. There is nothing stored in array

Comment: I currently have a checkbox which located at the first. Is there any other way to skip the first checkbox? Also, is there any way to format the items in array to be surrounded with '' ?

Comment: @Gwen, first make clear what exactly you want? Do you want to skip the checked box or what?

Comment: I only wanted to skip the first checkbox

Comment: @Gwen means you don't want to add value|id of first checkbox into array?

Comment: Yeah, it will just skip the first checkbox no matter checked or not checked

Comment: @Gwen check only fiddle

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing stored in the type_filter array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = new Array();
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked'))       
   arr.push("\"" + $(this).val() + "\"");   

});
```

[try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z78h6/)

Comment: you want the id or value?

Comment: It works but do you know how to format the item in array to be surrounded by '' each?

Comment: if you want only wrap with "" use "\"". I have edited the response again